# Multiple ng-repeat in one select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

May I know is it possible to create multiple ng-repeat in one select options element?

For example,

```
<select ng-repeat="thing in things, item in items"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Concatenate your two lists at the controller level and iterate over one list.

```
$scope.things = [1,2,3];
$scope.items ["item", "item2"];
$scope.combined = $scope.things.concat($scope.items);
```